# Could we add structs to Java?

Tags: java, struct, value-type

I've got asked this question at an interview and was unable to answer. Hope you can help me.

The question was: Why didn't Java guys add support for structs? Why is it impossible to add value types allocated on the stack to Java?

I suppose there should be some backwards compatibility issues with previous java versions? I am, however, unable to come up with any.

Comment: What is a struct, that isn't already covered by classes?

Comment: You have probably mess up a language tag.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth Seems like they're comparing it to c# where a struct is a value type whereas a class is a reference type

Comment: This has to be one of the dumbest interview questions. We don't know why they did what they did. We can speculate all we want, but we don't know WHY they chose not to implement a particular feature.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth Yes, like C# structs, which are reference types and allocated on the stack.

Comment: Here's a blog post on the subject: https://blogs.oracle.com/jrose/entry/value_types_in_the_vm

Answer (score 3):

While Java doesn't allow Stack allocation, it does use something call Escape Analysis.

Found a link that touches on this: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jtp09275/index.html

> The Java language does not offer any way to explicitly allocate an object on the stack, but this fact doesn't prevent JVMs from still using stack allocation where appropriate. JVMs can use a technique called escape analysis, by which they can tell that certain objects remain confined to a single thread for their entire lifetime, and that lifetime is bounded by the lifetime of a given stack frame. Such objects can be safely allocated on the stack instead of the heap. Even better, for small objects, the JVM can optimize away the allocation entirely and simply hoist the object's fields into registers.

Comment: Interesting that the JVM is able to perform escape analysis implicitly, but there seems to be no interest in having such analysis be part of the language (e.g. being able to specify that a parameter to an interface method must not be allowed to escape), since from a semantic perspective such a feature could eliminate the need for many redundant "defensive copy" operations.

Answer (score 2):

I think a `class` with public variables comes very close to a `struct`:

```
final class Person {
   String name;
   int age;
}
```

So there is no need to add something like `structs` if this type of functionality is already covered by classes.

Comment: It depends how far you want to copy C#'s structs, really. Structs can't inherit from another struct which will be possible here, just to name a difference.

Comment: Thats true and I have to admit I am not very familiar with C#. My point is that you don't need a construct that does *less than something that already exists*.

Comment: It acts like a struct but an instance of it will be a reference rather than a value

Comment: @JeroenVannevel We want it allocated on the stack.

Comment: @user1096294 Using escape analysis, the JVM can place the object on the stack.  This doesn't mean it does of course. ;)

Comment: This doesn't allocate the object to the stack.

Answer (score 1):

If the essence of the question was in the "Why is it impossible to add value types allocated on the stack to Java", then the answer should have been that data in Java is located in the heap, and passed by reference in the stack, except for generic types.

Comment: Could you expand on how are generics different in this case?

Comment: they are not, generics is just another form of compile time type check, at run time they are no different from "normal" classes. it's not the same as templates in C++.

Answer (score 1):

A structure is essentially a group of variables fastened together with duct tape.  Copying a structure or passing it by value to a method is equivalent to either copying all of the variables or passing them all by value.  If one never modifies any of the variables in a structure outside its constructor, except by rewriting them all, then the semantics of a structure will mirror those of a class; some people think that everything should behave like a class, and that structures which can be used in any other fashion are "evil", but for cases where *what one wants is a group of variables fastened together with duct tape* an exposed-field structure is ideal.

Consider, for example, the design of a `Point3d`, such that a variable of type `Point` encapsulates three `float` values, called `X`, `Y`, and `Z`.  Ideally, one would like to have each variable, array slot, or other storage location of type `Point` encapsulate those three values and nothing else, such that two storage locations are considered equivalent if and only if all three coordinates match.  An exposed-field structure would encapsulate that meaning perfectly, since a field declaration `Point3d foo, bar;` would allocate space for six `float` fields `foo.X`, `foo.Y`, `foo.Z`, `bar.X`, `bar.Y`, and `bar.Z`.  If one were to say `foo=bar; foo.X=5f; bar.Y=7f;`, that would be equivalent to `foo.X=bar.X; foo.Y=bar.Y; foo.Z=bar.Z; foo.X=5f; bar.Y=7f;`.  Because `foo.X` and `Bar.X` are different variables, as are `foo.Y` and `bar.Y`, the write to `foo.X` won't affect `Bar.X`, and the write to `bar.Y` won't affect `foo.Y`'.

If `Point3d` were an immutable class type, it would be impossible to say `foo.X=5f;`; it would instead be necessary to do something like `foo = new Point3d(5, foo.y, foo.z);` which is apt to be clunkier, slower, and more bug-prone.  If it were a mutable class type, one could say `foo.X = 5f;`, each storage locations of type `Point3d` would encapsulate not just the coordinates, but also a connection to every other storage location holding a reference to the same instance.  A storage location which holds the only extant reference to a particular `Point3d` instance could be used to encapsulate just the coordinates, but the only way to expose the information would be to copy it to something else (perhaps another `Point3d` instance).

It's worth noting that in addition to having structure types, .NET also has the concept of a "byref".  In C#, if `Point3d` is a structure and one defines a method:

```
void MovePointRight(ref Point3d pt, float amount) { pt.X += amount; }
```

and calls it:

```
MovePointRight(ref foo, 5.3f);
```

then *while the method is executing*, `pt.X` will refer to `foo.X`, and likewise with `.Y` and `.Z`.  In Java, the only way to make variables available for a method so it can store information in them is to create an instance of a class object containing those variables and pass a reference to it; there's no controlling what the method might do with that reference.  It could, for example, pass the reference to some other thread that will change the object at some future time.  In C#, code which passes a byref to a variable can be certain that by the time the called method returns, the byref and all copies of it will have evaporated. Passing `ref foo` will allow `MovePointRight` to do anything it wants to `foo.X`, `foo.Y`, and `foo.Z`, but any changes that could happen as a result of the call will occur *before* it returns.

Adding structures to Java might be somewhat possible with the JVM if they didn't have to work with generics.  Simply have each structure definition define multiple discrete variables and have an array-of-structure definition define multiple arrays.  Given `Point3d[] myPoints;`, a request to create a four-element array should create three four-element arrays of `float` and assign them to `myPoints.X[]`, `myPoints.Y[]`, and `myPoints.Z[]`.  Structure types aren't terribly useful, though, absent support for generics and byrefs.  There might be ways of kludging byref support if every method that had any variables that were passed by ref declared a class to hold such variables, produced a new instance on entry, and discarded it on exit, but performance would be relatively poor.  Making structure types work well would require a major overhaul of the JVM, and I doubt that's ever going to happen.